# How can I block users from changing the src of an iframe?

Tags: security, iframe, content-security-policy, src

I am limited by the platforms I am using.
I need to use an iframe to display personalized data. Due to the nature of the data, it uses a query in the iframe src. If that is changed (using devtools), there is a possibility that a user could see someone else's data, which is obviously not ideal for security purposes.
The query part is required because the end platform uses a variable to identify the user to the source platform.

I've tried setting up a CSP with the frame-src parameter, but that doesn't work because of the required query.

Comment: You can't really stop the user from making any change to your page or requesting any URL from your server, but it seems the iframe isn't the problem here. The problem seems (from your description) to be that the backend system would allow a malicious user to successfully request a URL that they do not have permission to. Is the backend service able to be modified, or is that a fixed element in your design? Can you proxy it? I've seen legacy environments brought into iframes by adding opaque ids for requests that are then proxied into the legacy service.